# Strange error while requesting user token

Tags: gentics-mesh

I am able to login to the API and get back a bearer token, however if I then try to request an api token for the admin user, I get:

```json
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "internalMessage": "The rest endpoint or resource for given path {/api/v2/users/715ece57728243a993dce051949d2e90/token} could not be found. Please verify that your Accept header is set correctly. I got {application/json}. It must accept {application/json}"
}
```

The uuid was copy/pasted from `/mesh-ui/#/admin/users/715ece57728243a993dce051949d2e90`

I have both `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers set to `application/json` in the request. The API request is going to localhost with stock install (`mesh-compose`) using the `gentics/mesh:1.7.1` image. All I've done in the UI is login as the admin to set the first password.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers, and thank you for your time!

**edit**

I noticed `MeshRestClient` is sending requests to `/api/v1`. Is this expected? Am I using the wrong endpoint perhaps? For clarity, my ultimate goal is to request an API token I can give to `MeshRestClient` so it can login without user/pass combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only api changes for v2 are within the GraphQL endpoint. So loading the token should work for API v1 / v2.

Loading a new token must be done via a `POST` request.

See https://getmesh.io/docs/api/#users__userUuid__token_post

I suspect you are using the wrong HTTP method.

POST is used since this operation is modifying the user and to avoid accidentally generating a new toke when pasting the URL in the browser.

The previously issued token will be invalidated.

Comment: Yes indeed! I was using GET. Cheers, and thank you!